# .ShellExecute and Wait

Tags: vbscript

I've got a VBScript that calls multiple other scripts. (Most of them are just copying files from NAS to multiple places on users PC.

One of the VBScripts needs to be run as administrator using `.ShellExecute`.

It does work but there are other VBScripts after it's call that rely on it, so I get an error for the files are missing.

I know the command

```
shell.Run "sample.vbs", , True
```

for waiting till the script is done.

Is there a similar way to get `ShellExecute` to wait?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ShellExecute` always runs asynchronously. If you have other scripts that need to run only after this script finished you could create some kind of marker upon completion to signal "go" to the other script(s).

For example, you can create a file in a specific path:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CreateTextFile("C:\path\to\marker.txt", True)
```

If you need to run your batch of scripts more than once, have the script remove the marker when it starts and re-create it at the end.

The script that's supposed to run next needs to check for this marker and suspend execution until it appears. For example:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Do Until fso.FileExists("C:\path\to\marker.txt")
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

Other options are creating a registry value, or an eventlog entry.

Checking the process list (e.g. via `Win32_Process`) won't work, because normal users don't have access to the `CommandLine` property of elevated processes (which would be required to identify this particular process).